# How to change if financial year change invoice number change in symfony stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, stored-procedures

I'm trying to achieve change Invoice no when change financial year

Eg: Invoice no 2017-2018 financial year

```
Invoice no       | Date
EXP/17-18/02567  | 25/03/2017
EXP/17-18/02568  | 26/03/2017
EXP/17-18/02569  | 27/03/2017
EXP/17-18/02570  | 28/03/2017
```

The new financial year will start from 01/04/2018, The new Invoice number will starts from `EXP/18-19/00001` I'm trying to change the financial year in the invoice number, but I'm facing difficulty in changing the Invoice number starts from `00001` is symfony stored procedures

Here is there my symfony stored procedures code

```
select  concat('EXP/',from_financial_year_,to_financial_year_,'/',(case when max_ref_id_ is null then lpad(1,4,0)
else
(case when DATE_FORMAT(year_,'%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y') then lpad((max_ref_id_+1),4,0)
                    else lpad(substring_index((max_ref_id_+1)/9999,'.',-1),4,0) end )
                 end))

            into exp_ref_no_;
```

Please help me out from this

Comment: Based on the procedure it looks like it will start over from 1 when `max_ref_id_` is null. You haven't given us enough information to know where that comes from but it appears to be the key to having the numbers start over with 1.

Comment: @Dave Check this link for the complete procedure it's too lengthy, check this  link for complete scripts  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aiZ6EDs3zRM4p98Gdgt3BN/0 financial year is fixed from in the scripts

Comment: The `svk_apt_expense_invoices` table appears to be the key here but I'm not exactly sure what might cause it not to have an entry for a customer in the current year that would result in `max_ref_id_` being null.